# How do I draw an arc based on two given points and a given height describing a circle segment?

Tags: java, graphics, geometry, trigonometry, segment

I'm trying to draw an arc based on two given points and a given height describing a circle segment. To acomplish this I would use the following method from java.awt.Graphics.

```
drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
```

First I observe that the x, y, width and height values describes a rectangle containing the circle.

> The center of the arc is the center of the rectangle whose origin is (x, y) and whose size is specified by the width and height arguments. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

So first I start by calculating the x,y,width and height values. The picture below describes how I would do this.

[image]

The first picture shows what values I've already got. The arc in the first picture is exactly what I'm trying to draw. In picture number two I calculate the lenght of a line between the two points. My code to perform this step would look like this:

```
int dx = p1.x- p2.x;
int dy = p1.y - p2.y;
double len = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)dx, 2) + Math.pow((double)dy, 2));
```

As shown in picture three I can now calculate the radius of the circle by using the following function.

```
radius = h/2 + len^2 / 8h
```

The first problem I encounter is to calculate the CenterPoint of the circle. This is partly where I need help.

If I was to calculate the Center Point I can then easily find the x, y, whith and height coordinates.

```
x = centerPoint.x - radius;
y = centerPoint.y - radius;
width = radius * 2;
height = radius * 2;
```

The last part is to calculate the startAngle and arcAngle based on the values we already calculated.

**TL;DR** I need help with calculating the angles and the center point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Less a Java problem and more a Math problem.

Comment: I was thinking that at first. But it's not really the geometry that is the problem, it's rather the coordinate-system that makes it all confusing..

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/geometry/GCG6/RCir.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a well-known relationship (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223110118/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55037.html), for instance) between the chord half length, the height of the arc (also called the *sagitta*), and the radius. Let the chord length (the distance between p<sub>1</sub> and p<sub>2</sub> be *l* = 2 *d*, let the arc height be *h*, and let the radius be *r*. Then

> *r* = (*d* <sup>2</sup> + *h* <sup>2</sup>) / (2 *h*)

The center is on the perpendicular bisector of the chord, at a distance *r* - *h* from the chord, on the opposite side from the arc.<sup>1</sup> You can then use standard inverse trig functions to get the start and end angles for the chord.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that it is not enough to know *p*<sub>1</sub>, *p*<sub>2</sub>, and *h*; you need some way of identifying which side of the chord has the center and which side has the arc.</sub>